# "You're too clever a man"

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-order, indefinite-articles, big-mess-construction

> You're too clever a man to imagine this.

The above sentence was [said by George Galloway](http://www.tubechop.com/watch/693555), a man of excellent rhetorical skills.

Since he said it, I doubt it's wrong, grammatically. But, I wonder if there is an explanation for this. Because adjectives always come after the article not before it. e.g. *You're a clever man.*

How could this be, grammatically?

Comment: "... adjectives always come **after** the article **not before** it" -- you will learn that there are exceptions to this rule. Therefore, the sentence **is** grammatical.

Comment: You could also write that as: "You're too clever of a man." I imagine, in speaking those words, the "of" dropped off, leaving you with the above quotation. If you consider it that way, you could probably come up with numerous examples of parallel constructions. "It's not that type of a place." "We don't have that fun of a relationship."

Comment: @tylerharms. Do you have any authentic citations to support your claims about _You're too clever of a man_ and _We don't have that fun of a relationship_? As a native speaker of English, I would never say either, and I have never seen or heard them.

Comment: @Barrie England: I agree those two (esp. the second) sound really clunky. But ["too nice **of** a man"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22too+nice+of+a+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) does occur, and doesn't really grind my gears too much. And I can't see any real grammatical issues distinguishing *nice* from *clever*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. _Too nice of a man_ seems very odd to me, and it must be rare. There are no records for it in the COCA, the BNC, the OED, or nGrams.

Comment: @Barrie: I certainly agree that *"of"* is at least a bit odd. GBooks only had about 90 instances, and without it, ["too nice a man"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22too+nice+a+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is about 20 times more common. But I'd have to say that particular *"of"* doesn't bother me anywhere near as much as *"I wouldn't **of** said this if I'd known how to talk proper"*.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: "Not that kind of a place" or "Not that type of guy" are both very familiar to me. The construction "that ______ of a _____" occurs a lot in spoken English, which is what the OP is concerned with.

Comment: @tylerharms: In those examples it is "that *noun* of a ____", here it is "too *adjective* a ____".  That might be where the difference lies.  Certainly the phrase "too clever a man" seems completely natural to me.

Comment: I haven't looked it up, but my experience is that "too clever of a man" is a peculiarly American construction. I've never heard a British person use it even very informally, but I've seen it in even fairly formal US writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surely grammatical. I'm still trying to find some definitive reference on the web. Meanwhile, you may want to read [this thread](http://www.englishpage.net/showthread.php?3399-So-Too-Adjectives-a-Noun).

[This page](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-understanding-so-and-too/) is helpful, but again I don't think it's definitive.

To me, sentences like *He is a too/so big man* are never correct. We need to restructure the sentence as *He is too/so big a man*. Alternatively, you can safely say *He is such a big man*.

Comment: Thank you. That helped very much. 

He is too kind a guy to refuse.
How established a technical writer is he?

Comment: "Lull is not just an English word, but also a so poetic one."
Yesterday, I wrote an essay in which I included the above sentence. I think, according to your answer, the sentence is wrong, and I should have used "very" instead of "so", right?

Comment: @BrightPolyglot "very" is fine while "such a poetic one" will do too.

Comment: That means "also a so poetic one" is wrong?

Comment: @BrightPolyglot Yes I think so.

Answer (score 11):

This is an example of a **Big Mess Construction**:

> - This is too big a mess (for anyone to clear up).

You'll find the same format in a number of other cases:

> a. She made *too rude* a remark (for me to repeat).
> b. She made *so rude* a remark (that we were shocked).
> c. I’ve never heard *as rude* a remark (as that).
> d. He doesn’t look the type to make *this rude* a remark.
> e. He doesn’t look the type to make *that rude* a remark.
> f. I wonder *how rude* a remark she could have made.
> g. Don’t be offended, *however rude* a remark she makes.
>
> — [The Big Mess Construction](http://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/LFG/19/papers/lfg14arnoldsadler.pdf)

In every one of these, the adjective must come before the article for it to be grammatical.

There are numerous academic papers on the subject, but they're heavy with jargon and hard to summarize. In other words, the name fits.

The easiest explanation is: it's idiomatic.

---

It's actually been around for a long time. In an unrelated search, I discovered this quote from 1576 (via OED):

> No man could be able to endure so colde, darke, and discomfortable a Nauigation.
>
> — 1576   H. Gilbert *Disc. Discov. New Passage Cataia* vi. sig. E.iiij<sup>v</sup>

Comment: The linked paper sheds good light on the description of how this works grammatically. It's sometimes called "degree fronting," referring to the fact that words of degree (like *too*, *so*, or *how*) have to go before the determiner (*a/an*) rather than after; and they bring with them the adjectives they modify.

Comment: Are {[Det quant] + [Adj comp] + [a] + [N]} ( **[How] much longer a journey** was it to your old job? **and** {[neg Particle] + [Adj comp] + [a] + [N]} structures (Theirs is **no bigger a house** than ours) structures included in the 'Big mess Constructions'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The linked paper doesn't seem to mention either of those at all. I think it would be best to ask a new question or two about it.

Comment: "Idiomatic" appears to be an unacceptable characterization: it is necessary, in order to apply this label to a construction, to determine that the meaning is not recoverable from the combination of the words in that construction. The same meaning results from the same words in "too rude a remark" and "a remark too rude".

Comment: @LPH "Idiomatic" here isn't a synonym for "idiom", but rather "natural", like something practiced over hundreds of years until it became second nature.