# "Many+a+adjective+plural noun" structure

Tags: grammar, many-a

Does the structure "I have had many a worse days/years/meals" have a specific name?

Comment: It’s “many a worse day,” not days.

Comment: Why would it have a name? There are thousands of things like that. Can you imagine being forced to name them all and to remember them all?

Answer (score 2):

There’s no name for that because it’s not a structure. If you use “a”, you can’t use a plural noun here.

It has to be either “many worse **days**” or “many **a** worse **day**”.

The adjective is not an essential element of the construction: “many days” and “many a day” are also grammatical. The latter construction has been called the “[big mess construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92079/youre-too-clever-a-man?noredirect=1)”; see the linked page and the other questions linked to there for further information.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler mentioned in a comment.

> It's a fixed-phrase quantifier *many a* used with a truncated comparative construction *worse (than X)*. There's no special name for it, no. English grammar is almost all such syntactic puzzle pieces linked together, instead of tenses and numbers in paradigms like Latin.